# Eloquent WHERE AND with "sub" OR

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a question regarding the `WHERE` clause

in the query I would like to say

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE link.hos_id = $hos_id
AND   outcome.otc_otrdischargedate = $td
AND   outcome.otc_outcome LIKE ['%ICU%', '%I.C.U%', '%L3%']
```

but instead it reads like this

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE link.hos_id = $hos_id
AND   outcome.otc_otrdischargedate = $td
OR    outcome.otc_outcome LIKE ['%ICU%', '%I.C.U%', '%L3%']
```

how should the laravel query be structured to read like the first example?

```
    $matchThese = ['link.hos_id' => $hos_id, 'outcome.otc_otrdischargedate' => $td];
    $icu = DB::table('link')
        ->join('demographic', 'link.lnk_dmgid', '=', 'demographic.dmg_id')
        ->join('admission', 'link.lnk_admid', '=', 'admission.adm_id')
        ->join('outcome', 'link.lnk_otcid', '=', 'outcome.otc_id')
        ->where($matchThese)
        ->orWhere('outcome.otc_outcome', 'like', '%ICU%')
        ->orWhere('outcome.otc_outcome', 'like', '%I.C.U%')
        ->orWhere('outcome.otc_outcome', 'like', '%L3%')
        ->orWhere('outcome.otc_outcome', 'like', '%Level3%')
        ->orWhere('outcome.otc_outcome', 'like', '%Level 3%')
        ->orWhere('outcome.otc_outcome', 'like', '%Intensive Care Unit%')
        ->get();
    $icuSize = sizeof($icu);
```

**SOLUTION   -- THANKS  @Mehravish Temkar**

different query, but same principal

```
    $array_conditions = array('%ICU%', '%I.C.U%','%L3%','%Level3%','%Level 3%','%Intensive Care Unit%');
    $step_down_icu = DB::table('link')
        ->join('daily_link', 'link.lnk_id', '=', 'daily_link.dlk_lnkid')
        ->join('admission', 'link.lnk_admid', '=', 'admission.adm_id')
        ->join('outcome', 'link.lnk_otcid', '=', 'outcome.otc_id')
        ->where('admission.adm_referraldate', '=', $td)
        ->where('outcome.otc_outcome', 'like', '%ICU%')
        ->Where(function ($query) use($array_conditions) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($array_conditions); $i++){
                $query->orwhere('outcome.otc_outcome', 'like',  '%' . $array_conditions[$i] .'%');
            }
        })->get();
    $step_down_icuSize = sizeof($step_down_icu);
```

Comment: for the multiple options - ['%ICU%', '%I.C.U%', '%L3%'], did you try whereIn and pass array instead of writing separate orWhere condtions?

Comment: Replace orWhere to where. Use where for AND  and orWhere for OR

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
$array_conditions = array('%ICU%', '%I.C.U%','%L3%'); 

$matchThese = ['link.hos_id' => $hos_id, 'outcome.otc_otrdischargedate' => $td];
    $icu = DB::table('link')
        ->join('demographic', 'link.lnk_dmgid', '=', 'demographic.dmg_id')
        ->join('admission', 'link.lnk_admid', '=', 'admission.adm_id')
        ->join('outcome', 'link.lnk_otcid', '=', 'outcome.otc_id')
        ->where($matchThese)
        ->whereIn('outcome.otc_outcome', 'like', $array_conditions)
        ->get();
    $icuSize = sizeof($icu);
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this one, but unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: @morne it doesn't show the desired records or are there any errors?

Comment: @morne http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34329886/laravel-querybuilder-how-to-use-like-in-wherein-function

Answer (score 1):

Just switch the `orWhere()` with `where()`. The query builder will chain the SQL clauses with *AND*.

```
$matchThese = ['link.hos_id' => $hos_id, 'outcome.otc_otrdischargedate' => $td];
$icu = DB::table('link')
    ->join('demographic', 'link.lnk_dmgid', '=', 'demographic.dmg_id')
    ->join('admission', 'link.lnk_admid', '=', 'admission.adm_id')
    ->join('outcome', 'link.lnk_otcid', '=', 'outcome.otc_id')
    ->where($matchThese)
    ->where('outcome.otc_outcome', 'like', '%ICU%')
    ->where('outcome.otc_outcome', 'like', '%I.C.U%')
    ->where('outcome.otc_outcome', 'like', '%L3%')
    ->where('outcome.otc_outcome', 'like', '%Level3%')
    ->where('outcome.otc_outcome', 'like', '%Level 3%')
    ->where('outcome.otc_outcome', 'like', '%Intensive Care Unit%')
    ->get();
$icuSize = sizeof($icu);
```

Comment: um...   Obvious_Solutiuon = Face_Palm. Thanks