# Laravel Eloquent: Extract all entries that begin with a list of provided string

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

The following request extract all entries from the users table where name=Albert or name=Alberto or name=Ana.

```
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->whereIn('name', ['Albert', 'Alberto', 'Ana'])
    ->get();
```

Is there is possibility to adapt this request to extract all entries **that begin with** the following names ?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34330385/3584881) if helps

Answer (score 7):

Use the like operator on the basic `where` function:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->where('name', 'like', 'T%')
            ->get();
```

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses)

**Edit:**
Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34329886/laravel-querybuilder-how-to-use-like-in-wherein-function/34330385#34330385) (but simplified), here is a simple closure that solves your question:

```
$queryStr = ['Albert', 'Alberto', 'Ana'];
$users = DB::Table('users')            
    ->where(function ($query) use ($queryStr) {
         foreach($queryStr as $q){
            $query->orwhere('name', 'like',  $q . '%');
         }      
    })->get();
```

Comment: Yes but in your example there is only one string to check. I would like to make the request with the provided array of string

Comment: That's not possible. How is the same string supposed to start with both "Albert" and "Ana"? No string matches that. Maybe you mean `->orWhere()`.

Answer (score 3):

Why not chaining `orwhere` clause:

```
$names = ['Albert', 'Alberto', 'Ana'];

$users = DB::table('users');

foreach ($names as $name) {
    $users->orWhere('name', 'like', $name.'%');
}

$users = $users->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

`->whereRaw(name in(\'Albert\', \'Alberto\', \'Ana'\)')`

or

```
->where(name, 'LIKE', 'Albert%')
->orWhere(name, 'LIKE', 'Ana%')
```

Comment: Please augment your code-only answer with some explanation, in order to reduce the impression that StackOverflow is a free code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

#### Simplest method

The simplest method is nesting the `where` and `orWhere` methods of the QueryBuilder:

```
<?php

$users = DB::table('users')
            ->where('name', 'like', 'Albert%')
            ->orWhere('name', 'like', 'Alberto%')
            ->orWhere('name', 'like', 'Ana%')
            ->get();    

?>
```

#### More general applicable for large array of names

You can use the `whereRaw` method of the QueryBuilder, and combine this with some basic php and sql. In this way MySQL injection is also automatically prevented.

```
<?php

$names = [
    'Abert',
    'Alberto',
    'Ana'
];

$conditions = [];
$sqlnames = [];

// of course you can append the wildcards directly, 
// but this is more general applicable
foreach($names as $name){
    $sqlnames[] = $name . '%';
    $conditions[] = '`name` LIKE ?';
}


// run the query
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->whereRaw(implode(' OR ', $conditions), $sqlnames)
            ->get();

?>
```

Comment: In terms of performance, what is the best method ? Use whereRaw or use where closure ?

Comment: In general raw SQL is always faster. And if you refer to my example: it is fastest if you hard code the SQL query instead of generating it from the $names array.